# How to find the origin of each Single Nucleotide Variants (SNV) in child when having variant call data for both parents?

Tags: human-genetics, dna-sequencing, snp

I am working with a trio (Mom, Dad, Child). I have variant call data for all three. Now I want to know each SNV in the child comes from which parent?
Is there any tool that could help me to achieve this goal?

Many thanks,
Vahid.

Comment: I think this is more suited to the Bioinformatics beta. If the post is migrated there, I can help you, as long as you give more information on the kind of data you are working with. Note, there is a plugin called parental-origin in bcftools which does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If a SNP is present in a child it is also present in at least one of the parents (except for de novo mutations which are fairly rare). So just check which parent has which polymorphism. For a question like that you would write a script yourself to check that.